# Microk8s doesn't start without internet access

Tags: networking, server, internet, snap, microk8s

I have a mickrok8s install from snap that after a power off doesn't start **without internet** access. Need a solution for not depending on the internet accessibility for my local cluster to work.

Trying to get the status will generate a bunch of:
`The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:16443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Can you tell us the detail of the machine you have the cluster set up on? Is it running on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

There has been some discussion on the microk8s github about this issue here : https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/1653

Maybe it helps as a solution was proposed there which worked for the issue reporter:

> It's working now and I will list out what I did for the benefit of others.
>
> Assuming 192.168.210.32 is your master node IP address.
>
> 1. Run `sudo ip route add default via 192.168.210.32` for ALL VM nodes (Worker nodes too otherwise pulling image from local docker registry wouldn't work).
> 2. Disable and enable dns in microk8s
> 3. Run `sudo snap restart microk8s`
> 4. Remove worker-nodes from cluster and add them back. You should now see `Join node with: microk8s 192.168.210.32:25000/JSKjpIGPOcVsJWKrKeoNOGbKdvvYiCiF`, notice the IP is now your master node IP (it was the router IP if you have internet connection I think?).
> 5. For me, I encountered ImagePullBackErr in the VMs that hasn't assign a hostname to 192.168.210.32. The pull error was fixed once I assigned 192.168.210.32 with the same hostname as the master node VM's. i.e. I append the line `192.168.210.32 master-node` to `/etc/hosts`